# for loop in HttpServer misbehaves

Tags: java, http, httpserver

I have this weird problem with a for loop.
This loop only iterates once while it should iterate more times (it has 3-4 elements in it, depending on something irrelevant.

Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("Executing " + url);
System.out.println("_elements.size()=" + _elements.size());
for (Object el : _elements) {
        System.out.println("element class:" + el.getClass().getName());
        if (el instanceof DynamicServlet) {
            ((DynamicServlet) el).execute();
            _stringBuff.append(((DynamicServlet) el).getOutput());
            }
        if (el instanceof String)
            _stringBuff.append((String)el);
} // for

System.out.println("finished for loop");
```

The program prints the following lines:

Executing /admin.dsp

_elements.size()=4

element class:java.lang.String

Notice that it never gets to print the last System.out.println! It mysteriously breaks and exits. 
There is no Exception thrown or anything, and this code section is being by the "handle(HttpExchange)" method of com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Attach a debugger and trace to find out?

Comment: 1)try put all you method code in `try{}catch(Throwable){} ` block. 2)Is there any multithreading?

Comment: @Dan Grossman I did try to put a breakpoint here and there, but nothing happens, the thread simply goes back to its starting position.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *know* that no exception is being thrown ? Or simply that no exception is being reported ? I would wrap the contents of the iterator block in a `try/catch` and report any exceptions.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I had a NPE thrown but somehow the thread was still alive or something. Maybe the sun's implementation catches any Exception and simply doesn't throw it to the default error-stream.

Comment: @yacov, you may answer your own question below and accept it as the answer or accept this answer as the correct answer.